# Vim: Show function hints or signature for PHP

Tags: php, vim, hints

I've got my nice PHP syntax highlighting all set up and it looks great. What I need now is the ability to show built-in function signatures or hints while typing.

This is so common in so many IDEs, I would think somebody has a plugin to do this for VIM.

Example: While in insert mode, and typing str_replace, somewhere on the vim screen would say "mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )"

Does anyone know of a good plugin for this? If not for PHP, then maybe something that can be ported to php using the right function definitions file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [TagList](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) plugin. One of it's features is showing function signatures in the status bar. See also [this tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/). TagList uses exuberant-ctags to parse your PHP files. Have a look at [this article I wrote](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2008/11/patching_exuberant-ctags_for_better_php5_support_in_vim/) to see how you can tweak/patch exuberant-ctags to make it work a little better with PHP5.

Comment: Sander your article is awesome! Thanks!