# Configure vim to show expected variables of PHP functions

Tags: php, vim

PHP has some pretty inconsistent parameters for functions (e.g. sometimes first `haystack`, then `needle`, and sometimes the other way around). I'd like vim to somehow hint at what parameters are expected. I mostly care for integrated PHP functions, not for project-specific functions. Is this possible to set up / configure?

My idea is that I type:

`strpos(`

and vim tells notifies me it expects `$haystack, $needle`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of Vim do you use?

Without any additional plugin or configuration, hitting `<C-x><C-o>` after typing a couple of letters of a builtin function you are supposed to get the omnicompletion menu *and* a small preview window showing the signature of the currently selected function. See `:help compl-omni` and `:help ft-php-omni`

With `strpos(`, you should get:

```
strpos(string haystack, mixed needle [, int offset] | int
```

You might want to try [this slightly better omnicompletion script for PHP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171).

Answer (score 2):

The excellent vim plugin [PIV](https://github.com/spf13/PIV) does something quite similar. If you press `shift-K` on a function, you get an in-vim offline view of the function's manual page -- Which doesn't only show what parameters the function expects, but also how to use them.

That's only one of PIV's useful features. It can for example also auto-fill a parameter with a known variable when you press `<tab>` in in the function's brackets. (I do believe this requires SuperTab to be installed though)

Answer (score 0):

[Tag List](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) might help you. See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191016/vim-show-function-hints-or-signature-for-php)